# SVN commits fail after hang-up

Tags: svn

First, my SVN commit process hung up.

After this, all subsequent commits failed with error:

> Can't open file '/var/svn-repos/projects/db/txn-current-lock': Read-only file.
>
> The command svnadmin recover /var/svn-repos/projects failed with error:
> Can't open file '/var/svn-repos/projects/db/write-lock': Read-only file system

How can I recover the SVN repository?

I'm running Debian, SVN 1.6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the cause of SVN errors was the hard disk failure. Bad clusters and so on.